# How to properly convert date

Tags: php

Im trying to arrange my date for the latest date entry, I have a date format and set it to ISO-8601 year number.

```
$currentdate =mktime(date('H'),date('i'),date('s'),date('m'),date('d'),date('o'));
```

I need to store the values from my database, since the last Month of the currentdate is
December 2013 I'm expecting to get the same value for my timestamp. 
unforunately I get a differnt date instead, the value of my $currentdate in timestamp (1420022147). When I try to view my date using

```
$val ="1420022147";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
echo date('M-d-Y H:i:s',$val);
I get this Dec-31-2014 18:35:47
```

Did I use the function wrong?
How do I turn my year to 2013?

Comment: not sure what you're doing with the `$currentdate` variable

Comment: additionally, the issue is up the tree somewhere, `1420022147` is indeed dec 31 2014. So your problem is wherever you're setting `$val`. Show us where / how you're setting `$var`

Comment: thank you for the reply, I apologize for the unclear variable declaration. my $currentdate is used to store the values on my database using mktime. as for my $val, I only used this as an example showing what values I got from my database. I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

to get current timestamp use strtotime function as follows

```
$current_time = strtotime(date('d-M-Y g:i:s A')); // eg : 1388729310
```

again if you want to convert into date you can use any format of date you want

```
echo date('d-M-Y g:i:s A', $current_time); // output : 03-Jan-2014 6:08:30 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question but I think you need to set the `$currentdate` after setting `date_default_timezone_set`. Also `$currentdate` can easily generated by the function `time()`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$currentdate = time();
$val = $currentdate;
echo date('M-d-Y H:i:s',$val);
```